# asp.net-mvc routing does not route with this anchor element

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

For asp.net-mvc routing, my link is this:

```
<a href='product/product_description/#:product_id#' >
```

but it is passing as this:

```
http://localhost:58166/product/product/product_description/1102
```

I expected it to be:

```
http://localhost:58166/product/product_description/1102
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: just post your anchor tag code...

Comment: you are using areas in your project???

Comment: i am using kendo ui and the value passed is preprocessor directice for column in database table

Answer (score 0):

You need to perpend forward slash

```
<a href='/product/product_description/#:product_id#' >
```

However you would be much better off using a helper rather than hard coding

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link text", "product_description", "product" { new ID = ?? })
```

Comment: http://localhost:58166/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fproduct%2fproduct_description%2f1101  is given by it

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. You question indicated your current url is `localhost:58166/product/..` .Perpending the forward slash will make the url relative to the domain root resulting in `localhost:58166/product/product_description/..` Where does `../Account/.. come into it?